# Copy a session for a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, session

I need to have two sessions with the same data. How can I accomplish this?

My scenario: the user has accumulated some data in the session while traversing the site. They click a button and now I fire off a thread to record what I've got. Unfortunately, the code I've inherited passes the session ID and uses that to access the data. More unfortunately, this recording takes some time, so users frequently hit other pages and mess up the data I'm recording.

- The user needs a session that they can continue to play with
- My thread needs a session that's not going to change

Ideally I'd be able to copy the session data into two sessions, one for each. **I'd really like a solution that somehow gives me these two sessions** because refactoring the code would be a nightmare. I realize this seems nigh impossible. The closest I can figure is to copy the data, invalidate the session, recreate it for the user, and then pass the invalid session id to the thread and hope it hasn't been cleaned out—not a plan I trust.

**If there is no other way, *please* suggest alternatives.** Priority is on speed of refactoring; otherwise, *overall* elegance.

More on the implementation: the thread fires off a number of requests, including the session ID, each of which generates a PDF, based off the data gathered in the session, which is merged by the thread into a master document.

Comment: A shallow copy of the session might not be sufficient if the objects in the session are mutable and might be modified by succeeding user actions. Can't you just collect a minimum set of information that is sufficient for the background task to complete its work?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that the process in this thread would need an actual session as opposed to a datastructure with certain elements from the session.

Comment: How would you guys work around the requests using the session ID?

Answer (score 1):

In your shoes, I'd store some data object in the session. When you need to start a thread to process this data, then you can clone the data object, not the session itself. Of course, you'll have to write some code to perform a deep copy on this data object, but at least your session will be just a wrapper (as sessions usually are).

And creating a data object to store all the data your thread needs somewhat establishes some sort of "contract", so if any other developer needs to add or remove anything from this data object, he/she will notice that the deep copy method must be also updated (hopefully).

Comment: What about the requests the thread fires? Those need access to the data as well.